# Split en un Switch JAVA

Tags: java, split

necesito ayuda con un problema, ya que he intentado usar el método split en un switch, y no sé como es porque no logro que me salga bien. Necesito que si el usuario mete dos palabras separadas por un espacio, el switch me devuelva ambas traducidas, no solo una.

Mi código:

```
String palabra;
String objetos[] = new String[3];
String comida[] = new String[3];
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
// Pedimos al usuario que introduzca una palabra
System.out.println("Introduce una palabra");
// Leemos la palabra introducida:
palabra = teclado.nextLine();
teclado.close();
// Definimos la tabla de las palabras objetos
objetos[0] = "coche";
objetos[1] = "silla";
objetos[2] = "cristal";
// Definimos la tabla de las palabras comida
comida[0] = "naranja";
comida[1] = "fresa";
comida[2] = "platano";
//Utilizamos switch
switch (palabra) {
    case "coche":
    System.out.println(comida[0]);
    break;

    case "silla":
    System.out.println(comida[1]);
    break;

    case "cristal":
    System.out.println(comida[2]);
    break;

    case "naranja":
    System.out.println(objetos[0]);
    break;

    case "fresa":
    System.out.println(objetos[1]);
    break;

    case "platano":
    System.out.println(objetos[2]);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Una vez que lees una línea de texto desde el teclado, usas split para separar las palabras:

```
String linea = teclado.nextLine().replace("\n",""); //quitamos el fin de linea
String [] palabras=linea.split(" "); //el separador será el espacio
```

Entonces tendrías que recorrer el array de palabras para ir buscando una a una:

```
for (String palabra: palabras) {
    switch (palabra) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un ejercicio y sin saber las restricciones para realizarlo no he querido entrar en detalles. Como comentas, se podría mejorar en muchos aspectos pero me he querido centrar en el problema actual sin "hacerle la tarea"

Comment: Entendido. Borrando comentarios...

Answer (score 0):

​
Si usas `split()` puedes crear un array conteniendo las palabras, en este caso el separador será " "

```
  String[] palabras = palabra.split(" ");
```

Por ejemplo si introduces:

```
Mi silla es naranja
```

obtendrás el array:

```
[Mi, silla, es, naranja]
```

En base a lo anterior, puedes iterar sobre este array

```
//Obtiene palabras de array palabras
for (String palabraaBuscar : palabras) {

switch (palabraaBuscar) {
    case "coche":
    System.out.println(comida[0]);
    break;

    case "silla":
    System.out.println(comida[1]);
    break;

    case "cristal":
    System.out.println(comida[2]);
    break;

    case "naranja":
    System.out.println(objetos[0]);
    break;

    case "fresa":
    System.out.println(objetos[1]);
    break;

    case "platano":
    System.out.println(objetos[2]);
    break;
}

}
```

---

Puedes simplificar tu código aún más realizando una iteración sobre el arreglo obtenido a partir de las palabras ingresadas. En este array, busca las palabras en los array objetos y comida, puedes usar [Arrays.asList(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) para convertir el array en una lista y usar [.contains(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) para buscar una coincidencia

```
    //Obtiene palabras de array palabras
    for (String palabraaBuscar : palabras) {
        //Busca coincidencia en array objetos
        if (Arrays.asList(objetos).contains(palabraaBuscar)) {
            System.out.println("Contiene: " + palabraaBuscar);
        }

        //Busca coincidencia en array comida
        if (Arrays.asList(comida).contains(palabraaBuscar)) {
            System.out.println("Contiene: " + palabraaBuscar);
        }
    }
```

---

Este sería el cambio de acuerdo a tu código:

```
    String palabra;
    String objetos[] = new String[3];
    String comida[] = new String[3];
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Pedimos al usuario que introduzca una palabra
    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra");
    // Leemos la palabra introducida:
    palabra = teclado.nextLine();

    //Crea array en base a palabras introducidas.
    String[] palabras = palabra.split(" ");

    teclado.close();
    // Definimos la tabla de las palabras objetos
    objetos[0] = "coche";
    objetos[1] = "silla";
    objetos[2] = "cristal";
    // Definimos la tabla de las palabras comida
    comida[0] = "naranja";
    comida[1] = "fresa";
    comida[2] = "platano";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(palabras));
    System.out.println(objetos.length);
    System.out.println(comida.length);

    //Obtiene palabras de array palabras
    for (String palabraaBuscar : palabras) {
        //Busca coincidencia en array objetos
        if (Arrays.asList(objetos).contains(palabraaBuscar)) {
            System.out.println("Contiene: " + palabraaBuscar);
        }

        //Busca coincidencia en array comida
        if (Arrays.asList(comida).contains(palabraaBuscar)) {
            System.out.println("Contiene: " + palabraaBuscar);
        }
    }
```